# error message using if ,or,statements in blank cell using excel

Tags: excel

my excel sheet is like this:

```
status| question1| question2 | question3
------|----------|-----------|-------------
 yes  |  q1      |           |
 no   |  q1      |           |
 yes  |  q1      |    q2     |     q3
 yes  |          |    q2     |
```

when the status is 'yes' and if any questions are blank then a warning message will be populated like this "please answer all questions".
i have used this equation

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"Please Answer This Question","")
```

but this is not working properly.

Comment: what about a highlight with a conditional formatting rule?

Comment: What do you mean not working properly?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to handle this in my mind:

1. Create a column that just counts rows that have a value. Column E: `=COUNTA(B2:D2)` If the value doesn't match the total number of questions, you know one is missing.
2. Use your initial IF idea but check all cells. Column E: `=IF(AND(A2="yes",OR(ISBLANK(B2),ISBLANK(C2),ISBLANK(D2))),"Please answer all questions")`
3. @Jeeped is right, you can use conditional formatting if you have a later version of excel.

Comment: by using this equation there is another problem ,like if conditions all true, then a 'false' word is inthe E Column. hw can i avoid that word?

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: by using this equation there is another problem ,like if conditions all true, then a 'false' word is inthe E Column. how can i avoid that word? and when new status like yes or no insert, the eqn doesn't work